# Panels on the space station module

Tags: modeling, procedural

I would like to model a space station in Blender. As you can see in the pictures, the individual modules are covered with aluminum panels. Is there any way to procedurally cover an object with panels (or with anything else)? It would be nice if I could set different numbers of panels around the perimeter of the module. As well as different number of panels per length.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Saturn V, these are all reasonable questions, but not all in the same place; the answers would have to be modelling tutorials.. SE sites aim to be archives of answers  to specific problems. Please go ahead and edit to isolate one task, and we can re-open for you.

Comment: Thanks, Saturn V, for your understanding.